# Remove substring using shell script

Tags: shell, sed

How do I remove a substring from a string using sed?

For example: 
I need to remove from all this:

```
/opt/openet/cdm/applications/SubscriptionManager/fwhome/config/log/corCTE_SM.pid process 18312 is not running
```

everything before `CTE_SM` and after too.

I need to extract `CTE_SM` from this line.

How do I do this?

Thank you so much.

Alessandro Melo

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your string is always has capitals, I am replacing the lowercase letters & then splitting the string using awk.

you can try splitting the text even before replacing with sed.

```
myString='/opt/openet/cdm/applications/SubscriptionManager/fwhome/config/log/corCTE_SM.pid process 18312 is not running'   
echo $myString | sed 's/[a-z]//g' | awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

result= `CTE_SM`

**alternatively**

```
echo $myString | awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

result= `corCTE_SM`